# Attribute Based Encryption

Tags: encryption, abe

Could someone explain the main differences between Key Policy Attribute Based Encryption (KP-ABE) and Ciphertext Policy Attribute Based Encryption using an example?

I know that KP-ABE depends on the private keys associated with the person trying to decrypt the message while the CP-ABE depends more on the attributes used in encryption. I would like to see an example that explains this part more to get a better idea.

Comment: [This answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/17894/706) has a good explanation. Can you clarify what that answer does not have that an answer to your question should have?