# How does ABE decryption works?

Tags: encryption, functional-encryption

I am trying to understand how Attribute Base Encryption (ABE) works. So, after downloading libfenc library from [here](https://code.google.com/p/libfenc/), I built the source code on Ubuntu 12.04 without any error.  Afterward, I tried to follow the library [commands](https://code.google.com/p/libfenc/wiki/FENCToolkitHelp) as follow:

- Create the master secret and public parameters:

  `abe-setup -m CP`
- Generate key for user's attribute:

  `abe-keygen -m CP -a 'ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE' -o userCP.key`
- Encrypt the input file under a given policy:

  `abe-enc -m CP -i filename.txt -p "((ONE and TWO) or THREE)" -o outfile`

With each executed command a file is generated (three files among which the encrypted file is created).

Now, when I try to decrypt the encrypted file *"outfile"* using:

`abe-dec -m CP -k userCP.key -f outfile.cpabe`

no file is generated at all, and I don't know if the encryption mechanism works or not !! does the code works or not !! am I missing something ?

#### EDIT ([from comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30772/how-does-abe-decryption-works#comment71313_30772))

Through this question I am seeking understanding the ABE encryption. It is not about the library AT ALL. it is about the basic understanding of the ABE mechanism. Believe me, the code itself is useless.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the usage of a library, not about crypto

Comment: Dear @cygnusv, thank you for your fast response. However, through this question I am seeking understanding the ABE encryption. It is not about the library AT ALL. it is about the basic understanding of the ABE mechanism. Believe me, the code itself is useless.

Comment: Also, I will appreciate if you could point me to where I should post this question @cygnusv, cheers

Comment: If you are interested in understanding ABE, then you should drop that library and instead read introductory information, such as the Wikipedia entry, [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17893/what-is-attribute-based-encryption) on Crypto.SE, or scientific papers on the matter.

Comment: What is your question? Remember that this site is for questions and answers. Questions should be narrowly scoped and answerable.